# Windows Printer API Hooking using Easyhook

Tags: windows, printing, hook, easyhook

I'm trying to Hook the `WritePrinter` function present in `winspool.drv` using `Easyhook RhInstallLibrary`.

**Injector.cpp:**

```cpp
NTSTATUS nt = RhInjectLibrary(
    processId,   // The process to inject into
    0,           // ThreadId to wake up upon injection
    EASYHOOK_INJECT_DEFAULT,
    NULL, // 32-bit
    dllToInject,         // hook.dll
    NULL, // data to send to injected DLL entry point
    0// size of data to send
);
```

`In hook.ddl`, the following function is created to hook printer function:

```cpp
BOOL MyWritePrinter(HANDLE hPrinter, LPVOID pBuf, DWORD cbBuf, LPDWORD pcWritten)
{
    //Some Code
    return  WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBuf, cbBuf, pcWritten);
}
```

The data stream passed to the printer is present in `pBuf`. But I'm not able to get that data.
How can I read data from `pBuf`?

**WritePrinter Function Reference:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145226(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What have you tried and what/how did it fail? pBuf is a pointer to an array of bytes, the length of which is in cbBuf

Comment: @JustinStenning I have tried almost every type casting but no result.
Yes, you are right about pBuf and cbBuf. Can you tell me how to get data from pBuf and convert it into string ?